# AutoML Tables "Invalid values"

Tags: google-cloud-automl

Trying to import my CSV data into Google Cloud AutoML Tables module, I don't have any error during the upload, but then in the ANALYZE tab, the **invalid values** field for each of my column is equal to my number of lines without any explanation. 
I followed the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare?&_ga=2.235991681.-1235097023.1559044596#csv) advices but don't find any information nowhere about what can explain this problem...

The consequence is that my training is KO and doesn't find anything, whereas correlation with target, means and standard deviation are well computed.

csv sample :

```
Followers,Followings,Tweets,Fav,NbDaySinceLastTweet,CommonFollowers,FollowBack
6624,2333,1697,8844,6,10,false
7702,5421,4211,755,1,10,false
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKOFC.png)

Comment: Google develop response : 

Hello,

I'm an engineer on AutoML Tables. This is a bug on our side that is causing the invalid value count to erroneously include all rows. We are hiding the count from the UI until this gets fixed, which should happen in the next few weeks. In the meantime, you should be able to still train your models if the rows are actually valid. 

Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for bringing this to our attention! I'll update this thread when the problem is fixed.

Anish